# Specifying exact market to fetch data from

Tags: api, cryptocurrency, coingecko

I have this GET request (I am using CoinGecko v3 API):

> https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=bitcoin%2Cethereum&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=24h

and here is the response:

```
[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin",
        "symbol": "btc",
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "image": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579",
        "current_price": 37282,
        "market_cap": 695279311602,
        "market_cap_rank": 1,
        "fully_diluted_valuation": 779474926827,
        "total_volume": 52300678011,
        "high_24h": 38849,
        "low_24h": 34846,
        "price_change_24h": 2176.11,
        "price_change_percentage_24h": 6.19871,
        "market_cap_change_24h": 40112069740,
        "market_cap_change_percentage_24h": 6.12242,
        "circulating_supply": 18731668.0,
        "total_supply": 21000000.0,
        "max_supply": 21000000.0,
        "ath": 64805,
        "ath_change_percentage": -42.55568,
        "ath_date": "2021-04-14T11:54:46.763Z",
        "atl": 67.81,
        "atl_change_percentage": 54799.24708,
        "atl_date": "2013-07-06T00:00:00.000Z",
        "roi": null,
        "last_updated": "2021-06-10T14:42:39.019Z",
        "price_change_percentage_24h_in_currency": 6.198713712795321
    },
    {
        "id": "ethereum",
        "symbol": "eth",
        "name": "Ethereum",
        "image": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/279/large/ethereum.png?1595348880",
        "current_price": 2520.14,
        "market_cap": 291669768272,
        "market_cap_rank": 2,
        "fully_diluted_valuation": null,
        "total_volume": 38753989678,
        "high_24h": 2636.43,
        "low_24h": 2491.85,
        "price_change_24h": -6.0279837,
        "price_change_percentage_24h": -0.23862,
        "market_cap_change_24h": -1426298398.7143555,
        "market_cap_change_percentage_24h": -0.48663,
        "circulating_supply": 116234761.124,
        "total_supply": null,
        "max_supply": null,
        "ath": 4356.99,
        "ath_change_percentage": -42.23601,
        "ath_date": "2021-05-12T14:41:48.623Z",
        "atl": 0.432979,
        "atl_change_percentage": 581168.88568,
        "atl_date": "2015-10-20T00:00:00.000Z",
        "roi": {
            "times": 89.12606988362417,
            "currency": "btc",
            "percentage": 8912.606988362417
        },
        "last_updated": "2021-06-10T14:42:34.517Z",
        "price_change_percentage_24h_in_currency": -0.2386217557990123
    }
]
```

I am interested in total_volume field and its value.

I am not sure, there is no explanation in the docs, how this value is calculated.
I guess, but maybe I am completely wrong, that this field gets its value like some average from all markets.

But how I would get this value from a specific market (say Binance).

Is there an endpoint for things like this, eg. to pass marketplace ID and to get data only from that market?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure but it seems to me that it's more a matter of the currency itself, not the market. It would be the total volume of exchange in 24 hours, how much of this currency has been exchanged in 24 hours?

The only point that disturbs me is the lack of a time indicator. But if I refer to this: https://support.coinmarketcap.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043395912-Volume-Market-Pair-Cryptoasset-Exchange-Aggregate. I think it's a quantity that was exchanged over a given time.

Comparing the value here: https://coinmarketcap.com/en/currencies/bitcoin/ in "Volume 24h" I see that the value is pretty much the same.

Comment: You seem right. total_volume is pretty much the same as what is shown as 24h volume on Coin Gecko site.